# Problems redirecting to an Activity with intents

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

**The problem:** Lets say I have 3 activities: MainMenu, LevelSelection and Game. I have a button that run an intent in MainMenu to redirect the player to LevelSelection. In LevelSelection is another button that redirect the player to Game. When the activity Game ends it run an intent to redirect the player to the MainMenu activity. However, when tested, the redirection is done to LevelSelection instead of MainMenu.

**MainMenu => LevelSelection code**

```
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LevelSelection.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

**LevelSelection => Game code**

```
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Game.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

**Game => MeainMenu code**

```
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest, I would set `No history` to `true` for all your activities.  This will prevent the user from going back to a previous activity when the current one closes (or when the user presses "back").  This might be helpful since you're trying to have strict control over what activity the user goes to.

I would also remove `this.finish()`.  I think you're closing the activity before the intent is started.  Hence why it goes back to the previous activity instead of the new one.

Another solution would be to set 'No history' to 'true' only for `LevelSelection`.  Then, you can simply close the 'Game' activity, and it should go back to `MainMenu`.

Comment: That will solve this problem in particular. However the application is more complex than just 3 activities I was wondering why that behavior was happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, while calling your **MainMenu** activity from **Game** activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);  
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

this.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

While starting level selection,

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

**MainMenu => LevelSelection code**

```
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LevelSelection.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

and if you want to go back from Game mode to main menu, simply use,

**Game => MeainMenu code**

```
this.finish();
```

Comment: That will solve this problem in particular. However the application is more complex than just 3 activities I was wondering why that behavior was happening. Thanks!

Comment: I think when the Game activity is finished, LevelSelection activity is restored. Try calling MainMenu activity without finishing Game activity.

Comment: It did not work either. In fact I'm running "finish()" before on every "redirection". For example when yo finish a level I call "finish()" and then call a method that know if must go back to the main menu (because the game ended) or to the next level. However I tried running "finish()" after calling the intent but the result is the same.